# Travelling to UK as visitor without minor son

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I'm filling application for my parents to visit the UK on a standard visitor visa, they will be leaving my younger brother(15) home due to his school. He will be looked after by my aunt who lives next door, do I need to provide a signed letter from my aunty that she will look after my minor brother when my parents visit the UK for 4 weeks? or do I have to explain this in the cover letter?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Usually it is good for getting a visa if you leave a minor child behind, one reason to go back home.

Comment: Personally I would explain this in the cover letter **and** provide confirmation from the aunt. Overstaying in the knowledge that any children will be looked after by relatives in the home country is not uncommon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UK immigration will not be checking that your son is being properly looked after. It's not their business. They only care whether your parents will follow the rules while they are in the UK and will leave at the end of their visit.

It will be helpful to mention your younger brother in the application, as having him at home demonstrates their ties to your home country, and provides a reason for them to return.